# Number of zeros in the decimal representation of the powers of 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Prove that for every natural number $m$, there exists a natural number
> $n$ such that in the decimal representation of the number $5^n$ there are at least $m$ zeros.

Before that I proved that for $m$ = $2^a$  $(a \ge 3)$, we have $Z^*_{m} = \langle -1\rangle_2*\langle5\rangle_{2^{a-2}}$.

These tasks are on the topic of primitive roots, so how can I reformulate my problem in these terms? I think these tasks may be related to each other, but I don't see how exactly.

Give me some tips please.

Comment: In other words, the number of zeros in the decimal representation of powers $5^n$ is  unbounded. I see it as a difficult problem (very difficult?).

Comment: @Piquito , most likely it`s not, this is a task from my seminar. it can be noted that decimal places in the powers of 5 is cyclic (and length of the every cycle is power of 2). May be it can help.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A063585 and https://oeis.org/A329172

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a much simpler method. Please notice that:

$$10^n \mid 5^{2^{n-1}+n}-5^n.$$

Hence, there is $m \in \mathbb N$ such that:

$$m \times 10^n +5^n=5^{2^{n-1}+n}.$$

Now letting $n \to \infty$ implies that there are **consecutive zeros** in the middle of $5^{2^{n-1}+n}$ as many as required since $10^n$ grows faster than $5^n.$

We are done.